# Did aptitude uninstall the gnome gui?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, aptitude, uninstall

Recently I wanted to remove the keyboard-configuration app for linux, so I typed

```
sudo apt-get remove keyboard-configuration
```

it prompted me if I wanted to remove a bunch of packages (17 MB), and now knowing the inner working of Debian, I complied. Next time I went to reboot the machine, it no longer boots to the os gui. Instead I get booted to a shell interface. Please see this image:

[image: Shell interface that my machine now boots to]

How would I troubleshoot to find the cause? And how would I fix it? The distribution is Debian.

EDIT: according to the apt log, the following was removed:

[image: packages that were removed]

Comment: can you see in `/var/log/apt/history.log` what packages were removed?

Comment: @Halfgaar Thanks, I have added the list of packages. What is your analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

and then reboot. That should do it. You removed the Xorg server, that's why you cannot boot into the GUI.